# Securing web application

Tags: security, https, sha

I am working on an application which has both web and mobile java interface. Web is only a "spectator", therefore can't alter database in any way. On the other hand, the java interface can (and it often does). I don't want to use self-signed certificate so I came up with this solution. What I want to ask is whether it could be considered secure or if there is any better, more efficient way to do this. I am a bit paranoid person so please take this in account.

When an android device registers itself, I save pasword as **sha256(pass + pass)**. This is the *only time* the device has to send password as a plain text. This function produces what I'll call **[hash]** and it will be stored in my database.

When logging in, the device sends new hash created by **sha256([hash] + unixTime)** as well as the unixTime. I need to use the [hash], otherwise I would not be able to verify the password. The server will try to reproduce the product of the function and if it succeeds, user is verified. Sent unixTime will be inserted into database afterwards, so I can also check, whether this time hasn't been used yet (if unixTime is less OR equal than saved, therefore forged / from past, I can safely discard it as invalid)

Similarly, all other packets which need authentication will be validated this way (so every packet = new hash)

Note: all hashes are converted to hex, just to spare a few bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to ask is whether it could be considered secure or if there is any better, more efficient way to do this.

"Could be considered secure" isn't asking much. I consider it secure against unauthorized login, as long as an attacker doesn't have access to the device, the network, or the database. A straightforward system that transmits and stores the password in cleartext would also be secure in that kind of situation. It would make more sense to ask with a specific security goal and threat model in mind.

Here are a few key problems that this design:

1. If an attacker can get the hashes from the database, they can log in by computing `sha256([hash] + unixTime)` without knowing the password.
2. An attacker that controls the network can intercept a `sha256([hash] + unixTime), unixTime` pair and use it verbatim. SSL would prevent such an attacker from obtaining those values.
3. If an attacker can get the hashes from the database, they can quickly try hashing passwords and see which users' hashes match. Salted hashes would prevent this.

Comment: To your second point, as I said, unixTime will be saved as well and compared in next request. If it's the very same (or even older), it will be discarded as invalid. So any hash will be only one-timer.

Comment: right, one time. an attacker that controls the network can prevent the delivery of the original legitimate use, so that the attacker can use it the one time that it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in addition to saying you don't want to use a self signed cert that you're also oppossed to using https even if it was a certificate issued from a trusted certificate authority; is that so and if so why? Having your password in plaintext even once is a significant vulnerability; that plaintext password is free game to anyone running packet capture software on machines that your network traffic traverses, not to mention that if you've chosen the wrong http method then those passwords will definitely end up sitting in the logs of any proxies along the way.

I'd also suggest that at the least you store your passwords properly salted. Not doing so results in a number of security weaknesses if your database is retrieved by a malicious party; for example pre generated rainbow table attacks would be feasible as well as an attacker being able to easily identify which users have identical passwords thanks to the hashes matching. There's a great Owasp writeup on the key things you should look out for [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet]).

Is using a solution like oauth an option? I recently implemented Google OAuth in a mobile application and it was pretty straightforward in combination with ssl. No need to reinvent the wheel, especially when it comes to crypto and user auth ;)

Comment: I was actually thinking about oauth before but I somehow forgot about it. Will give it a shot, thank you for a remainder.